# Left join with double nested selects in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I've got a fairly complicated query I've built up here. Its job is to select all details on documents which have not yet been approved (this much works), and returns me a list of the document references and the name of the user who submitted that document. What I then want to do is LEFT JOIN the table onto the results so that I get all the users who have yet to register their approval on those documents (which is what I'm doing in the nested select, i.e. anyone with approvalstatus = 'Pending', which I needed to identify which records needed adding.

```
SELECT substr(m.xreference,1,instr(m.xreference,'/')-1) Proj,
       m.xreference,       
       m.xversion,
       a1.assignedtoname,
       a1.actiondate
FROM   documentapprovers a1,
       docmeta m,
       (SELECT DISTINCT a2.documentid
        FROM   documentapprovers a2
        WHERE  a2.approvalstatus = 'Pending') penders
WHERE  penders.documentid = a1.documentid
       AND m.did = a1.documentid
       AND a1.approverrole = 'Author'
       AND a1.approvertitle = 'Author'
       AND a1.actiondate <= SYSDATE - interval '3' month
ORDER  BY proj ASC, a1.assignedtoname DESC, m.xreference asc
```

I tried to do a LEFT JOIN on nesting the above query like this:

```
SELECT a3.assignedtoname, a4.*
FROM (SELECT substr(m.xreference,1,instr(m.xreference,'/')-1) Proj,
               a1.documentid,
               m.xreference,       
               m.xversion,
               a1.assignedtoname,
               a1.actiondate
        FROM   documentapprovers a1,
               docmeta m,
               (SELECT DISTINCT a2.documentid
                FROM   documentapprovers a2
                WHERE  a2.approvalstatus = 'Pending') penders
        WHERE  penders.documentid = a1.documentid
               AND m.did = a1.documentid
               AND a1.approverrole = 'Author'
               AND a1.approvertitle = 'Author'
               AND a1.actiondate <= SYSDATE - interval '3' month) a4
LEFT JOIN documentapprovers a3
ON a3.documentid = a4.documentid
```

But I get the error that the command was not properly ended. I've gone over it again and again and it seems perfectly terminated to me. Can anyone help?

Please note it's a very old version of Oracle, 8i I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 8i is very, very old and ANSI joins were not part of the syntax until version 9i.

Try using the proprietary Oracle outer join syntax `FROM a4, a3 WHERE a4.documentid = a3.documentid (+)`.

Comment: Excellent! I had a suspicion it was this because I hadn't been able to get JOIN statements to work either, but I figured a mistake in my code was more likely than it not accepting the JOINs I am used to working.